# list comprehension not evaluating as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
z = [
[7,None], 
[9,None], 
[None,7], 
[None, 15], 
[None, None], 
[2,None], 
[0,None]]
```

..and wanted a list comprehension which will return the integer in the element if there is one even if it is 0 and and will return 1 for an element where both subelements are `None`.

I brought it as far as this:

```
[a or b if (a!=0 and b!=0) else 0 if set([a,b])=={0,None} else 1 if set([a,b])=={None} else -10 for a,b in z]
```

..which almost works, it returns:

```
[7, 9, 7, 15, None, 2, 0]
```

So it has failed to turn the element `[None, None]` into a 1. Does anyone know how to fix it?

The bit  `else -10` is just there as I believe a list comprehension written like this must end with an `else` if you leave that out it throws a `SyntaxError`

Comment: wouldn't it be better and more _readable_ if you use normal for loops with conditionals?

Comment: You are correct that the conditional expression `X if Y else Z` requires an `else` component, or else it throws a SyntaxError. This is true regardless of whether the expression is in a list comprehension. But if you never expect Z to execute in any circumstance, then there's not much point in having a conditional expression at all. Just replace `X if Y else Z` with `X`.

Comment: Also note that an `if` can appear inside a list comprehension without an `else`, for example `[i*2 for i in range(10) if i > 5]`. But this is not a conditional expression, and it can't come before the `for`.

Comment: `Simple is better than complex`, `Special cases aren't special enough`. Thinking about the problem in an organized way leads to @gmds' solution: check `a` first, then check `b`, then fill in the placeholder value when everything is `None`. Because `0` should *not* be handled differently from other integers, the code should therefore *not* compare values to `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
[a if a is not None else b if b is not None else 1 for a, b in z]
```

Output:

```
[7, 9, 7, 15, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Nice, comparing to *not* None here definitely makes it read more like English :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a genexp to filter out items that aren't identical to `None` and use it with `next` and a default value, eg:

```
[next((el for el in lst if el is not None), 1) for lst in z]           
# [7, 9, 7, 15, 1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write the expression as (calling the first element `a` and the second `b`):

```
(1 if b is None else b) if a is None else a
```

That immediately reads quite backwards, but that's how the ternary expression works. So the list comprehension is

```
[(1 if b is None else b) if a is None else a for a, b in z]
```